# Postgresql - Can I do a join in a function?

Tags: postgresql, join, functions

I'm recently starting to use PostgreSQL. In SQL Server I used to use stored procedures for different kind of things. I want to know if, like in SQL Server, can I do something like in that.
I used to use this kind of things;

```
create procedure my_proc
@opt int=null,
@param varchar=null
AS BEGIN
IF @opt = 1 
 select * from my_table1 t1
 inner join table2 on t1.id=t2.id 
 where t2.param=@param
END IF
IF @opt = 2
select "nothing"
END IF

GO
```

If the user return the @opt variable with 1 the result could be like:

```
t1_id | t2_id | param
2     | 2     | qer
5     | 1     | qer
8     | 1     | qer
```

and if the user return a 2 in the @opt it would be something like:

```
nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, except the Postgres syntax through [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) is  more natural:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_proc(myOpt bool, myParam varchar)
RETURNS SETOF (types)
AS $$
  SELECT types
  FROM my_table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 USING (id)
  WHERE myOpt AND t2.param = myParam
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you need a more complex procedural language check out [`PL/pgSQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 parts to your question if i read it right.

### **1.** **Can you perform joins between tables in postgresql (native or within stored procedures/functions.. etc)**

Answer: YES, just like in SQL Server, you can perform joins between tables. For example:

```
SELECT *
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.column1 = table2.column1);
```

Read more from this official page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

### **2. Can you write stored procedures in postgresql and pass parameters like shown in your question?**

Answer: Postgresql does not have the "Create procedure" syntax instead it uses "Create Function" for both stored procedures or UDF. You can call your parameters just like in SQL Server. This article gives an overview for starters: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew it was possible to do joins in psql. I'm reading in the article that i'ts near imposible to get more than 1 result from a select in a function....bassically that's what i wanted to do. In the example that I did, I can get various results ..like:

id - param
1 - asd
2 - asd
7 - asd

In postgresql the only thing I got is a success ....